# is there a way to add a parameter on a component method?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 10.3, and a component which reads SMS from a phone.
This components works like this:

```pascal
cmp.ReadSms;
```

After that, there is an event `onReadSMS` which is called for every message present.

I need to save each message in a database, but the database object is inside my main procedure.  I cannot reach my database from the event.

I was wondering if there is a way to pass my database object to the event so that I can do my inserting there.

EDIT:

Here is some code:

```pascal
unit myUnit;
    
TEventHandlers = class
  procedure ReadMessage(Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
end;
    
var myEvents: TEventHandlers; 
    
function SMSReceive(dbMain: TFDConnection): Boolean;
var cSMS: TGSMObj;
begin
  cSMS: TGSMObj.create(nil);
  cSMS.OnReadMessage := myEvents.ReadMessage;
  cSMS.ReadSms;
end;
    
procedure TEventHandlers.ReadMessage(Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
begin
  // Here I can read the SMS.
  // I would like to do:
  // dbMain.ExecSQL('INSERT INTO ...')
  // But dbMain is unknown here.
end;
```

Let me add also that this unit is called from some external thread, so I cannot have a global database object, but I need to pass it when calling the `SMSReceive` function.

Comment: You need to show your code (in your q), because it is not at all clear what you mean by "the database object is inside my main procedure".

Comment: I added some code, let me know if it's more clear now.

Comment: Please add actual code, not something you made up on the fly. The code you posted does not compile. Also, if the code above can't access the dataset, then there's no way you can use the dataset within the event handler. You have no control over when the event is called, so you can't modify its parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can add custom parameters to a pre-existing event (without altering the component's source code).  But there are some options you can try to manipulate how your event handler operates.

The easiest solution would be to just derive a new class from `TGSMObj` and add a `TFDConnection` field to it, eg:

```pascal
type
  TMyGSMObj = class(TGSMObj)
    DB: TFDConnection;
  end;

  // 'class' methods can be used as event handlers, so you don't
  // need to create a global object instance of this class...
  TEventHandlers = class
    class procedure ReadMessage(Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
  end;

function SMSReceive(dbMain: TFDConnection): Boolean;
var
  cSMS: TMyGSMObj;
begin
  cSMS := TMyGSMObj.Create(nil);
  cSMS.DB := dbMain;
  cSMS.OnReadMessage := TEventHandlers.ReadMessage;
  cSMS.ReadSms;
end;
    
class procedure TEventHandlers.ReadMessage(Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
begin
  TMyGSMObj(Sender).DB.ExecSQL('INSERT INTO ...');
end;
```

Or, if `TGSMObj` is a [`TComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent) descendant, you can use its [`Tag`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Tag) property to hold the `TFDConnection` pointer, eg:

```pascal
type
  TEventHandlers = class
    class procedure ReadMessage(Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
  end;

function SMSReceive(dbMain: TFDConnection): Boolean;
var
  cSMS: TGSMObj;
begin
  cSMS := TGSMObj.Create(nil);
  cSMS.Tag := NativeInt(dbMain);
  cSMS.OnReadMessage := TEventHandlers.ReadMessage;
  cSMS.ReadSms;
end;
    
class procedure TEventHandlers.ReadMessage(Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
begin
  TFDConnection(TGSMObj(Sender).Tag).ExecSQL('INSERT INTO ...');
end;
```

Or, you can use the [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) record to coerce the `Self` parameter of your event handler to point to whatever you want, eg:

```pascal
type
  TEventHandlers = class
    class procedure ReadMessage(Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
  end;

function SMSReceive(dbMain: TFDConnection): Boolean;
var
  cSMS: TGSMObj;
  Handler: TWhateverTypeOnReadMessageUses;
begin
  Handler := TEventHandlers.ReadMessage;
  TMethod(Handler).Data := dbMain;

  cSMS := TGSMObj.Create(nil);
  cSMS.OnReadMessage := Handler;
  cSMS.ReadSms;
end;
    
class procedure TEventHandlers.ReadMessage(Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
begin
  TFDConnection(Self).ExecSQL('INSERT INTO ...');
end;
```

Alternatively, using `TMethod` anyway, you can use a standalone procedure rather than a class method, eg:

```pascal
procedure ReadMessage(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
begin
  TFDConnection(Self).ExecSQL('INSERT INTO ...');
end;

function SMSReceive(dbMain: TFDConnection): Boolean;
var
  cSMS: TGSMObj;
  Handler: TWhateverTypeOnReadMessageUses;
begin
  TMethod(Handler).Data := dbMain;
  TMethod(Handler).Code := @ReadMessage;

  cSMS := TGSMObj.Create(nil);
  cSMS.OnReadMessage := Handler;
  cSMS.ReadSms;
end;
```

Or, a [class helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)) might work (I haven't tried this one myself), eg:

```pascal
type
  TFDConnectionHelper = class helper for TFDConnection
  public
    procedure ReadMessage(Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
  end;

function SMSReceive(dbMain: TFDConnection): Boolean;
var
  cSMS: TGSMObj;
begin
  cSMS := TGSMObj.Create(nil);
  cSMS.OnReadMessage := dbMain.ReadMessage;
  cSMS.ReadSms;
end;
    
procedure TFDConnectionHelper.ReadMessage(Sender: TObject; MessageText: WideString; PhoneNumber, CenterNumber: AnsiString; TimeStamp: TDateTime; TimeZone, Status, Index: Integer);
begin
  Self.ExecSQL('INSERT INTO ...');
end;
```

Comment: it's amazing how many things I haven't thought of. Thank you so much! So many things to learn. Is there a "preferred" inside this list or one is as good as another? Thank you again!

Comment: @lorife The generated codegen will be fairly similar no matter which one you use. But I did list them in order of preference (in my opinion).

Comment: One last thing. They all work event the last one. The first 2 are easy to understand. The last 3 are a little more complex for me. What should I read to learn more about the l those 3 approaches? Could you point me to a manual or similar? Even if not you be my day. Thank you so much

Comment: @lorife Those 3 approaches are undocumented. The `TMethod` approach is fairly well-known in the Delphi community, search around online for past discussions in various forums. In a nutshell, class/object method calls that use Delphi's `register` calling convention are represented by `TMethod`, where its `Code` field points to the method to call, and its `Data` field is the value to pass to the method's `Self` parameter. So, user code can tweak method calls, and event handler assignments, using `TMethod` directly. The class helper approach, I completely guessed at, so I'm glad it works.

Comment: I need a little more help. I have been trying your 1st method which works but I found out it has a strange behaviour. Very ofter it looks like the event does not get called. Instead if I use the standard event it gets called every time. How is this possible?

Comment: Also with 2nd method, same result. Could it be a problem when using "'class' methods can used as event handlers" ?  While I wait I'm going to try with a global object instance as before

Comment: I think I have found something. Problem is not the event. There is something wrong with the timing. After cSMS.ReadSms; i added cSMS.close; and freeandnil(cSMS). Just like that it does not work. If I add showmessage('test') before closing the component it works. Otherwise it does not. it does not work even if I change showmessage with sleep(1000). Shouldn't it first go into the SMSReceive function then go back for the "close"?

Comment: @lorife not if the receive operation is bound to the message queue of the calling thread, no.